# Append the columns and put one after other

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

| a1 | p1 | a2 | p2 | a3 | p3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ... |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | ... |

And, I want to create a dataframe like this:

| a | p |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 9 | 10 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 11 | 12 |
| ... | ... |

Comment: Please format your question accordingly. I can't comprehend what is your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
 import pandas as pd
 import random
    
 a = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(178) ]
 b = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(178) ]

 #Original DF
 df = pd.DataFrame({"0": a, "1": b})
    
    
 #New DF
 cf = pd.DataFrame()
 cf["Actual Value"] = df["0"]
 cf["Predicted Value"] = df["1"]
 cf["Error Value"] = df["0"] - df["1"]
 cf["Id"] = ["Bin" + str(i + 1) for i in range(178) ]
```

I misunderstand you with previous one.

This should fit you:

```
import pandas as pd
import random


#Original DF
d = {}
for i in range(int(178)):
    a = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(10) ]
    b = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(10) ]
    d["Bin " + str(i+1)] = pd.DataFrame({"0": a, "1": b})

con = pd.concat(d, axis=1)

colum = []
for i in range(178*2):
    if i%2 == 0:
        colum.append("0")
    else:
        colum.append("1")

con.columns = colum


#New DF
result = []
count = 0
for i in range(0,178*2,2):
    a = con.iloc[:,[i,i+1]]
    a["Error"] = a["0"] - a["1"]
    a["Bucked"] = "Bin: " + str(count)
    result.append(a)
    count = count + 1

result = pd.concat(result)
result
```

[Result image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQZRn.png)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Your code creates a single "0" and "1" column whereas I have in total 178 "0" columns and 178 "1" columns. Where each 0&1 combination represents one single bin. Here each bin has different number of actual and predicted values.

Comment: Just edited post, should be fine now.